# $f$ entire and $Im(f(z)) \leq Re(f(z))^2$ implies $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

My notes say to use Little Picard, with the hint hat $f$ will miss a disk. I don't see how to do that, instead I have:

$f$ entire $\Rightarrow$ $e^{-f}$ entire.

Now, $\mid e^{-f}\mid = e^{-Re(f(z))} \leq e^{Im(f(z))\frac{1}{2}}$ therefore $e^{-f}$ is bounded, hence constant by Liouville. Then, $f$ is also constant.

Is this correct? Also, how would you go about showing that $f$ misses a disk to use Little Picard instead?

Comment: Little Picard is too advanced for this simple problem. Map the outside of the parabola to the unit disc with a conformal map. Then composing $f$ with this you get a bounded entire function. By Liouville's theorem it must be constant.

Comment: @logarithm thanks, do you mean map the parabola to the boundary of the unit disk? I am afraid my geometric intuition is not strong enough to engineer out of thin air a map that would do that.

Also, when you say too advanced, do you mean that part of the proof to little Picard implicitly assumes the answer to this problem? Or that in the historical development of the subject it appears out of order to use Picard's result to solve a problem that would have been asked prior to the theorem? For someone not steeped in the culture of complex analysis this has always been confounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality is wrong. Use Picard's Theorem. $|(a+ib) -i| <\frac 1 2$ implies $1-b <\frac 1 2 $ so $b >\frac 1 2 >a^{2}$. Hence no point of the disk $D(i, \frac 1 2)$ can be in the range of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, how did you know to pick the disk centered at i with that radius?

Comment: Isn't it the other way around, $b \leq a^2$?

Comment: @Mike We have to get a contradiction to the hypothesis $Im(f(z) \leq Re(f(z))^{2}$ to show that the range does not intersect the disk. $b >a^{2}$ in my answer is correct. For your first question you can take any point on the $iy$ with $y >0$ and consider a small disk around it.

Comment: I see, so anything above the parabola defined by the inequality would be outside the range of $f$, thanks.